# Do I have to restart apache server each time I change a PHP script?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

It seems to me that I have to restart apache server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

each time I change a PHP script, if I'm using virtual host.

Pointing the browser to http://localhost/php-script-name.php works without Apache2 restart.

Pointing the browser to http://virtual-host-domain/php-script-name.php requires Apache2 restart.

Is it so?

Comment: nope, editing the php file does not require to restart Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "no" unless you have added rather weird things in your Apache config.

The most likely thing is that you accidentally didn't save your PHP script. (It happens to everyone—even when they try it twice. Tends to suddenly work if someone is watching.)

The second most likely is a caching problem. Try loading the page with `curl` instead of a web browser to eliminate a couple of possible sources of caching.